# Javascript sort not working with IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the problem is I have a list with contacts and when someone change his/her status I try to move them to the top of the list. Everything worked till now, with IE9, and Firefox 4 is not working. I show you the code:

```
function sortByStatus()
{

  var divs = getElementsByClassName(document,"status_sort");
  divs.sort(compare);

  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
  {
    $("#contact_info").append(divs[i]);
  }
}

function compare(div1, div2)
{
  var id1 = div1.getAttribute("id");
  var id2 = div2.getAttribute("id");
  if (id1 > id2)
    return 1;
  else if (id1 < id2)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea or possible fix? Thank you.

**update**

I have tried MrBuuBuu solution and it works patially, because now the sort by status works but the alphabetic sort is not working. I had to change part of MrBuuBuu solution, the compare function, because I compare the name of the contacts with a number just before the name that represent the status (ex. 2John , 2 means offline, and 1 online) so I have to compare with '<' and '>' and return 1, -1 or 0.

But what is worst, now it doesn't work with IE7 or IE8... the sort by status is not working.

Really weird, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName returns a NodeList, not an array. So you have to convert it to an array first. I also cleaned up your compare() function.

```
function compare(div1, div2)
{
  var id1 = div1.id;
  var id2 = div2.id;

  if (id1 < id2) {
      return - 1;
  }
  if (id1 == id2) { 
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

function sortByStatus()
{

  var divs     = document.getElementsByClassName("status_sort");
  var divArray = $.map(divs, function(div) { return div; });

  divArray.sort(compare);

  $.each(divArray, function(i, div){
      $("#contact_info").append(div);     
  });
}
```

Comment: I think my problem is id1 - id2, because they content, for instance, 2John and 1Peter, so the result is NaN. I need to figure out how to solve this, taking only the number. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the browser's native `getElementsByClassName` function, you may be ending up with a DOM node collection that is not a sortable Array.

When you say it's not working, are you getting any errors or is it just that the array doesn't get sorted? I'm assuming you're getting an error because `sort` in not defined.

One thing you could try is to clone the node collection to a plain JavaScript Array before sorting:

```
divs = [].slice.call(divs);
divs.sort(...
```

I don't have IE9 to test this, but with Chrome:

```
// undefined
document.getElementsByClassName("someclass").sort
```

But:

```
// the sort function
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("someclass")).sort
```

Comment: or if you dont want to instanciate an array, Array.prototype.slice.call(divs);

Comment: @Matt: You're right, but the extra verbosity for that optimization is usually not worth it.

Comment: No error, just the array doesn't get sorted. The sort function is never reached (tested with some alerts inside it). I will try your solution. Thanks

Comment: I mean the compare function is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it has been working? There's no such function as `getElementsByClassName` in the global scope.

Try using `document.getElementsByClassName("status_sort")` instead.

Comment: At one time, the getElementsByClassName was not a native DOM function and so there were various versions of it around. I suspect that is the case here, since his function takes the `document` object as a parameter.  But your advice is good.

Comment: Yes, tested wit IE7 and 8 and worked. I tried your solution with no luck, thanks anyway. ;)